# Why is the 1-year return of Mirae Asset India Equity Fund - Direct - Growth is being calculated as 10.6%?

Tags: india, mutual-funds

According to [Groww](https://groww.in), 1-year return of [Mirae Asset India Equity Fund - Direct - Growth](https://groww.in/mutual-funds/mirae-asset-india-opportunities-fund-direct-growth) is being calculated as `10.6%` according to the data pulled on 15-Mar-2019. However, I am not being able to verify that number from the data published (hover over the chart in the page linked above).

The NAV on 15-Mar-2019: `53.21`.
The NAV on 14-Mar-2018: `48.11`

CAGR: `(53.21-48.11)/48.11*100 = 10.60%`

However, the [difference](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=3&d1=14&y1=2018&m2=3&d2=15&y2=2019) between two dates is `366` days (last day not inclusive), which is 1 day more than 1 year. Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: I'm confused on the question - the NAV at the close of 14-Mar-2019 was 53.21 (mutual fund only post NAV at the end of the day). Even if you used 366 days as the basis the CAGR would be 10.57% and still round to 10.6%. What exactly is the confusion?

Comment: And not every year has 365.25 days. You are aware that there is a longer year every single 4 year period? They likely standardized and did not wan to get sued - so they rounded the year length up.